# Why can't i get this simple C program to work?

Tags: c, arrays

I am making a simple console program that is supposed to enable the user to enter an array and the program is supposed to display the arithmetic average of all the numbers, but no matter what I try I just cant get this to work. Can anyone here point out why this isn't working?

(This is in Serbian but you can probably see what is what.)

Edit: I get these errors when I run this code:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
F:\rastko\Documents\Code\C\Test1\main.c||In function 'main':|
F:\rastko\Documents\Code\C\Test1\main.c|49|warning: passing argument 1 of 'UnesiElementeNiza' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
F:\rastko\Documents\Code\C\Test1\main.c|19|note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'|
F:\rastko\Documents\Code\C\Test1\main.c|51|warning: passing argument 1 of 'AritmetickaSredinaNiza' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
F:\rastko\Documents\Code\C\Test1\main.c|29|note: expected 'unsigned int *' but argument is of type 'int'|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

And then the program crashes. I do not know what this means and my English is not the best when it comes to technical talk because i am learning how to code in Serbian.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 41

int BrojElemenataNiza(unsigned int brElem)
{

    if (brElem <= MAX){
        return brElem;
    }
    else {
        return 69;
    }
}

void UnesiElementeNiza(int niz[0], unsigned int brElem)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < brElem; ++i)
    {
        printf("niz[%u] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &niz[i]);
    }

}

double AritmetickaSredinaNiza(int niz[0], unsigned int brElem)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < brElem; ++i)
    {
        j = j + niz[i];
    }
    return j/brElem;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, j, niz[0];

    printf("unesite broj elemenata niza\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);                            //unos broja elemenata niza
    int brElem = BrojElemenataNiza(n);

    printf("unesite elemente niza\n");          //unos elemenata niza
    UnesiElementeNiza(niz[brElem], brElem);

    double arSredina = AritmetickaSredinaNiza(niz[0], brElem);
    printf("aritmeticka sredina niza je ");
    printf("%lf", arSredina);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "just cant get this to work" mean?  Please take some time to read [ask] also. FYI - dividing two integers is not going to return a double.

Comment: Any warnings of the C compiler? Did you try a debugger? Especially suspect is `niz[0]` as automatic variable.

Comment: the compiler produce 2 warning, have a look at those

Comment: Wow, the warnings even tell you the line number where the problematic code was found -- and what the problem is `:)`

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica - bah. Strong typing is for weak minds!

Comment: Also, C requires that an array declaration have a size greater than `0` [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) *"...the [ and ] may delimit an expression or \*. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. ..."* (@BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica ...chuckling `:)`

Comment: Back In The Day (tm) we passed ***everything*** as `int`! And we liked it that way!! We loved it!!!

Comment: Even better -- we didn't even tell you what we were passing until we got into the function. Types in parameter lists in parenthesis -- bah...

Answer (score 0):

What about this, sorry it is in English , I don't speak Serbian.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX 41

int check(unsigned int brElem)
{

    if (brElem <= MAX){
        return brElem;
    }
    else {
        return 69;
    }
}

void num_to_array(int *niz, unsigned int brElem)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < brElem; ++i)
    {
        printf("niz[%u] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &niz[i]);
    }

}

double average(int niz[0], unsigned int brElem)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < brElem; ++i)
    {
        j = j + niz[i];
    }
    return j/brElem;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, j, niz[MAX];

    printf("how many numbers ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);              //unos broja elemenata niza
    int brElem = check(n);

    printf("enter numbers\n");    //unos elemenata niza
    num_to_array(niz, brElem);

    double arSredina = average(niz, brElem);
    printf("aritmeticka sredina niza je ");
    printf("%lf", arSredina);


    return 0;
}
```